# heroku socket connection limitation

Tags: heroku

One of my app need socket connection.
I tested on nitrous.io, but their free account always close the socket connection if there is no signal between server and client more than 1 minute.

Just wonder if there is similar socket connection limitation on heroku?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has support for WebSockets, with the usual 30s timeout limitation. This can be easily worked-around by sending heartbeat packets.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets

Comment: The 30s limit is not mentioned under this link. Do you know where to find the info now? Thanks!